# .async syntax error while installing google assistant sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, magic-mirror

I am using python 3.7.3 version and i am getting an syntax error.

''''
(env) pi@raspberrypi: $ googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk-project-id ***** --device-model-id ********

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/env/bin/googtesamples assistant-pushtotalk", line 5, in  from googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk import main

File "/home/pi/env/Lib/python3.7/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 29, in

from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, retry if exception

File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tenacity/ init__.py", line 292

from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
''''

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do when you haven't even posted your code. We need a [mre] of your code to be [edit]ed into your post, and also we need the error as text in your post, not in a screenshot. We can only vaguely guess as to what the reason for the error is if we don't have your actual code.

Comment: The `tenacity` module you're using, whatever that might be, is too old to be compatible with the Python version you're running - it uses the name `async` which became a reserved keyword at some point.  Hopefully a newer version is available.